# How to make the spacing shrink before content while keeping the content centered

Tags: html, css

I want to keep my content centered and get the extra space used up first
I ve tried using percentages width, which helps me with centering but the spaces are always there

What would be the ideal way to make it happen?
I want the final result to be like this Oapletwo.com

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.11);
  border-right: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="brand">
    <h1>PaymoNeer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a missing `}` when I made you a snippet. I do not see any percentages in your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `text-align: center` on the .wrapper element and `display: inline-block` and `margin: 0 auto` on the .brand div to keep it centered.

```css
.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
  border-left: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.11);
  border-right: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.brand {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="brand">
    <h1>PaymoNeer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;` for your `.brands` div

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.11);
  border-right: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.brand {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="brand">
    <h1>PaymoNeer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center;` and adjust the padding of the content

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments.

If you actually show the code (click the `[<>]` snippet editor and elaborate), it is an answer instead of a comment and you can earn rep to be able to comment in the future.